# How to show all data points on radar chart using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, radar-chart

I would like to render a chart like this example using Chart.js [image: Example]

I have a chart config like this

```
  labels: ["Technology", "System", "People", "Process", "Influence"],
  datasets: {
    label: "Growth Up Chart",
    data: [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5],
  },
  options: {},
```

With this `data` attribute, it shows every point on each label line respectively in number. I have tried with `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` and it helps on displays the number on the point in the `data`

Now I want to displays all the other data point for all label line and in string in stead of number. E.g `['Creates', 'Masters', 'Evangelizes', 'Specializes', 'Adopts']` intead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and do the same for System, People, Project, Influence.

May I know how to implement that? Or any keyword to research on it?

Thanks a lot!